# Adding a string outside of JSON in Python json.dump

Tags: python, json, list, object

I'm trying to output a string outside of a JSON object using json.dump in Python.  I'm able to successfully output a JSON with the following code:

```
events = [] 

item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

#Do a bunch of stuff

 case = {'Artist': item['Artist'], 'Date': item['Date'], 'EventDate': item['eventDate'], 'Time': item['Time'], 'Venue': item['Venue'],
        'Address': item['Address'], 'Coordinates': coordinates, 'ArtistImage': item['artistImage'], 'Genre': item['genre'], 'OtherInfo': item['otherInfo'], 'ArtistBio': item['artistBio']}

        item[event] = case
        allEvents.append(case)

with open("events.json", "w") as writeJSON:
json.dump(item, writeJSON, sort_keys=True)
```

My output is as expected (a JSON):

```
[{"Address": "581 5th Street, Oakland, California 94607", "Artist": "Triangle Man", "ArtistBio": "No artist bio available", "ArtistImage": "https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/fallbackImage.png", "Coordinates": [-122.278385, 37.799161], "Date": "Wednesday, June 12th, 2019", "EventDate": "2019-06-12", "Genre": "No genre available", "OtherInfo": "No other event info available", "Time": "10:00 PM", "Venue": "Brix 581"}, {"Address":.........}]
```

However, I want the output to look like below: `"var events= "` as a string before the JSON.

[image]

I've tried:

```
eventsVariable = "var events = "
with open("events.json", "w") as writeJSON:
json.dump(eventsVariable, item, writeJSON, sort_keys=True)
```

But it gives me an error when I try to concatenate a string with a list. Can I do this using json.dump?

Comment: So all your data is in `item`? Just do `"var events = "+str(items)`

Comment: or simply call `writeJSON.write(eventsVariable)` and then `json.dump(...)`.

Comment: json.dumps returns a str, append your string "var events= " to json.dumps(data)

Comment: Basically, you're adding two different `type`s of items and the interpreter doesn't have a built-in way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dumping straight to a file with `json.dump`, use `json.dumps` to dump to a string first

```py
with open("events.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    file_str = json.dumps(item, sort_keys=True)
    file_str = "var events = " + file_str
    writeJSON.write(file_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach `json.dump(eventsVariable, item, writeJSON, sort_keys=True)` is incorrect since as per the [json.dump docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump), the first element has to be a valid json object, which `"var events = "` is not

You can append your `"var events = "` string to the json string returned by `json.dumps()`, and then save that string to your file.

You can use `string.format` or `f-strings` based on your python version, I have included both examples below

```
#Use f-strings for python >= 3.6
#s = f'var events = {json.dumps(data)}'
s = 'var events = {}'.format(json.dumps(data))
with open("events.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(s)
```